# VMware installation problem

Tags: vmware

i want to install VMware Workstation 9.0.2 on my computer but I keep getting this and I don't what to do:

> Please enter the user that will initially connect to Workstation
>   Server. Without setting this correctly, you will not be able to share
>   VMs with other users. Additional users and administrators can be
>   configured later in Workstation by selecting "Shared VMs" and
>   clicking)

What do I enter here? I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: just press enter key ...it will use your default username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, just keep hitting enter for that, and all the questions that follow, and VMware will set all to the defaults that it needs.  Below are some of the other questions that you'll be asked.

```
Please choose a directory for your shared virtual machines.

Please enter the port to use for https access to Workstation Server.
```

Comment: Thank you so much i kept pressing enter and it works :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have VMware Workstation 9 too. :)

Anyways, just put in your own username.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @UriHerrera Uhh, yes it does, you simply enter in your own username at the prompt (as stated above).

Comment: @haneefmubarak Your answer was tagged for deletion because of content and/or length, try to expand it more when answering.

Comment: @UriHerrera Sometimes a short answer is all you need. In fact, it would have worked with only the second line. While general policies exist to prevent answer spamming, taking time to write a longer answer which presents no more content doesn't help anyone.